# Instantiating a LUT and Initialising with a .coe for ModelSim/QuestaSim

Tags: vhdl, ram, xilinx, lookup-tables, vivado

### The Background

This LUT needs a width of 32 and a depth of 256.

So I have a LUT which was created by an IP core. Now I want to instantiate it myself to get it working in the sim (this also helps me learn all of the parameters myself). I've done this many times for FIFOs but never created a LUT before so please check what I've done looks correct. I just want to create a LUT of values and to be able to read them back. I used a block of RAM for this.

I've tried on two different computers with:

```
QuestaSim-64 10.2c_5
ModelSim SE-64 10.1b
```

### The Problem

So I can compile the code. When I try to open it:

```
vsim work.top
```

It opens the IDE and freezes on:

```
# Loading unisim.rb36_internal_vhdl(rb36_internal_vhdl_v)#1
```

If I remove:

```
INIT_FILE => "lut.coe",
```

Then it loads up fine. So I know that line crashes it.

### The LUT:

So I have a LUT, does this look correct to you? Is there any other ways to instantiate a LUT with a .coe file?

```
lut : RAMB36E1 
generic map(
    INIT_FILE => "lut.coe",
    READ_WIDTH_A => 36
    )
port map
    (
    addrardaddr => addr_lut,
    addrbwraddr => X"0000",
    cascadeina => '0',
    cascadeinb => '0',
    clkardclk => clk_i,
    clkbwrclk => clk_i,
    diadi => X"00000000",
    dibdi => X"00000000",
    dipadip => X"0",
    dipbdip => X"0",
    doado => data_lut,
    enarden => '1',
    enbwren => '0',
    injectdbiterr => '0',
    injectsbiterr => '0' ,
    regceb => '0',
    regcearegce => '1',
    rstramarstram => rst_i,
    rstramb => rst_i,
    rstregarstreg => rst_i ,
    rstregb => rst_i,
    wea => X"0",
    webwe =>  X"00"   
    );
```

Tried swapping the above out for 18kb RAM, same error:

```
# Loading unisim.rb18_internal_vhdl(rb18_internal_vhdl_v)#2
```

LUT:

```
lut : RAMB18E1 -- Simple Duel Port mode, 512 deep
generic map(
    INIT_FILE => "lut.coe",
    RAM_MODE => "SDP"
    )
port map
    (
    addrardaddr => addr_lut,
    addrbwraddr => "00000000000000",
    clkardclk => clk_i,
    clkbwrclk => clk_i,
    diadi => X"0000",
    dibdi => X"0000",
    dipadip => "00",
    dipbdip => "00",
    doado => data_lut_b,
    dobdo => data_lut_a,
    enarden => '1',
    enbwren => '0',
    regceb => '0',
    regcearegce => '1',
    rstramarstram => rst_i,
    rstramb => rst_i,
    rstregarstreg => rst_i ,
    rstregb => rst_i,
    wea => "00",
    webwe =>  X"0"   
    );
```

Comment: The usage of device specific primitives is very restrictive. I would suggest to use a generic description if possible. This solution can also be used by simulators without vendor specific primitive support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously. Throw away the IP core and the COE file. ((If that's the only place your data is, don't actually throw it away!)

```
Subtype Data_Word is std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
Type Lut_Type is Array(0 to 255) of Data_Word;
Constant Lut : Lut_Type := (
 0 => X"00000001",
 1 => X"00000002",
...
17 => X"DEADBEEF",
others => (others => 'X') );
```

Substitute your own coefficient of course. For bonus points, use a script or even a C or VHDL program to read the COE file and write the above chunk of VHDL.

Job done.

It's synthesisable, simulatable, and portable to other FPGAs.

(IMO the portability issue is the *real* reason for most vendors' IP cores. But I'll make an exception for complex cores like PCIe or DDR memory interfaces.)

Comment: This is actually me throwing away the IP core but figured I could still recycle the .coe file. Thanks, I'll have a look at this tomorrow morning when my brain is less fried

Comment: [COE File Syntax](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/cgn_r_coe_file_syntax.htm)

Comment: I guess with the above method - the tools still generates me a RAMB block

Comment: It normally would. If it refuses for some reason, (a) check your pipelining - you need a register on its address or output (the BRAM is synchronous) and (b) there is an attribute (something like `attribute RAMSTYLE of Lut is "BRAM";`) in the documentation which should force it. I don't recall the attribute being necessary but it's good to know.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple and short way for Xilinx tools to read *.mem or *.hex files directly in VHDL. The file content can be use in simulation and synthesis as BlockRAM initialization.

Xilinx offers a coding example in [UG901](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf#page=124) on page 124:

```
type RamType is array(0 to 7) of bit_vector(31 downto 0);

impure function InitRamFromFile (RamFileName : in string) return RamType is
  FILE RamFile : text is in RamFileName;
  variable RamFileLine : line;
  variable RAM : RamType;
begin
  for I in RamType'range loop
    readline (RamFile, RamFileLine);
    read (RamFileLine, RAM(I));
  end loop;
  return RAM;
end function;

signal RAM : RamType := InitRamFromFile("rams_20c.data");
```

The example is for a RAM but it can easily be converted to a ROM  (LUT) when you remove the write port and replace the signal with a constant.

A more advanced implementation can be found for example in [PoC.mem.ocrom.sp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocrom_sp.vhdl). This implementation also works with Altera's sltsyncrams, which csn read *.mif files.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good alternate answer. Though I wrote a short script which generate the above LUT which I will try out first. If that works, I'll try this out later as it looks a little more generic =D

Comment: I forgot to mention how the *.mem file format looks like: n lines for n memory words so 1 line per memory word; each memory word is encoded in hexadecimal ASCII characters.

Comment: A good way to use this answer would be to adapt the function to read .coe files directly, skip the lines you don't need, then extract coefficients from the useful lines.

Comment: @fiz Feel free to extend the ocrom to read new file formats :)

Comment: Cheers, since the .coe file is fixed for now I just scraped the values from that but I will try using this in future designs if I need it =)